# Error 3021 using subqueries in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I get the Error 3021 ("No current record found", but there are records to be found) when I run a query using a subquery as one of the variables.

Here's the code:

```
SELECT thefieldsiwant, etc.etc., 

(SELECT directory.person_name FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON doc.entity_to=directory.entity_id) AS receiver,

(SELECT directory.person_name FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON doc.entity_from=directory.entity_id) AS sender

FROM doc;
```

entity_id is the primary key for the table "directory".

entity_to and entity_from are foreign keys for the table "doc".

Basically I simply just want the person's name to appear if he is the sender of the doc (and another person's name as the receiver of the doc), and not the ID of those two particular persons.

Comment: You may not be able to stop the error - it is a common error. If you can't stop it, you can trap it using error handling.
Post back with more details of the form and event where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi SeeSharp, the event occurs when I load the form itself (or even just the query itself for this matter). I've been running just this code on SQL viewer, so it's not really related to a form event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting everything in the FROM like the code below. Also, if you use some of the below code, you should ensure that if one of the SELECT columns are NULL, Access returns a replacement value:

```
select  doc.documentname, 
        reciever.person_name, 
        sender.person_name 
from 
doc 
LEFT JOIN
    ((SELECT directory.person_name, doc.entity_to FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON doc.entity_to=directory.entity_id) AS receiver on doc.entity_to = receiver.entity_to)
LEFT JOIN   
    ((SELECT directory.person_name, doc.entity_from FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON doc.entity_from=directory.entity_id) AS sender on doc.entity_from = sender.entity_from)
where dir.entity_id = '[enter id for user]'
```

Comment: I tried this:

SELECT docfieldswhatever, receiver.person_name, sender.person_name
FROM 
((
doc
INNER JOIN
(SELECT directory.person_name, directory.company_name, directory.entity_id FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON directory.entity_id=doc.entity_to) AS receiver
ON doc.entity_to=receiver.entity_id
)
INNER JOIN
(SELECT directory.person_name, directory.company_name, directory.entity_id FROM directory INNER JOIN doc ON directory.entity_id=doc.entity_to) AS sender
ON doc.entity_from=sender.entity_id
);

but there were entries that duplicate itself.

Comment: Basically I kinda just want a query which will do something like a dlookup from directory given the person IDs in the doc for every record.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid having to do the dlookup through a form though that's why I'm doing just the SQL statement. :(

Comment: Got it! Thanks Greg Jones! I just removed the WHERE clause, added DISTINCT to the doc.documentname, and replaced INNER JOIN with RIGHT JOIN in the subqueries. Took me 4 hours haha